Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: Duplicate entry '' for key 'uq_mobile'
I cannot resolve this fatal error despite trying to debug it -- issue is a mySQL Insert statement
The error is:

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'uq_mobile' in
/home/path/public_html/signupvalidate.php:51 Stack trace: #0
/home/path/path/signupvalidate.php(51): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 {main} thrown in /home/path/path/signupvalidate.php on line 51

what is 'uq_mobile' ?  This is not a phrase anywhere in my code or mySQL database or table setup
The Insert statement is:
$stmtInsertProfile = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO users_profile (userid, firstName, middleName, lastName, mobile, email, country, registeredAt, lastLogin, intro, userProfile)
                                    VALUES (:userid, :firstName, :middleName, :lastName, :mobile, :email, :country, :registeredAt, :lastLogin, :intro, :userProfile)');

$stmtInsertProfile->execute([
    // 'id' => '', // do not specific the auto increment primary key on insert commands 
    'userid' => $fetchedUserID,
    'firstName' => '',
    'middleName' => '',
    'lastName' => '',
    'mobile' => '',
    'email' => $fetchedUserEmail,
    'country' => '',
    'registeredAt' => '',
    'lastLogin' => '',
    'intro' => '',
    'userProfile' => ''
]);


My exported table structure is:
CREATE TABLE `users_profile` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `middleName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userBio` text NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `registeredAt` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lastLogin` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `intro` tinytext DEFAULT NULL,
  `userProfile` text DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_swedish_ci;

The primary key is "id" in the table so it is not being referenced in the INSERT command.  $fetchedUserEmail (a valid email string) and $fetchedUserID (a valid integer) are both variables which contain the expected values when I output them during debugging

Can you show your create table statement? You have a unique key on the table, but it's not obvious from the error what that unique key is.

Yes. I have updated original post with the table structure.  thanks for responding

Odd, it's not there. The insert you showed is on line 51 of signupvalidate.php?

That doesn't show the constraint rule, which may be scripted separately. Look for the constraint named uq_mobile and show us that. I'm guessing from the name that it's saying your mobile field needs to contain a unique value on each row, but we ought to verify that

I did a control F in Visual Studio for "uq_mobile" and these words do not exist.  I have no data fields, no table fields, not databass or table names and no variables with the words "uq_mobile" in them.  I do not know where this word is coming from.  Maybe "mobile" is a reserved word and cannot be used as a mySQL name?

No, the error in particular pertains to a unique key on the table. Is $stmtInsertProfile->execute line 51 of signupvalidate.php?

Ok I found the error.  In the insert I entered an integer into the "mobile" field and now it works.  No error.. 'mobile' => '5555',    strange.. I guess mySQL doesnt like "mobile" as a field name...

It's not a keyword or reserved word. It's creating some sort of unique key based on the mobile and possibly the user ID.

in Visual Studio...no it would be in your database, not your application code. Do you have a tool like mySQL workbench or phpmyadmin to manage your database? Look there

now it works. No error...probably because you don't have 5555 as the mobile value on any other rows in the table. Whereas presumably you have '' (i.e. empty string value) in at least one other row already -hence why trying to insert it again would violate the unique constraint. There is no magic or strangeness going on here, I don't think. I guess mySQL doesnt like "mobile" as a field name...not sure how you reached that conclusion from the test you carried out??? You merely changed the value you inserted, not the field name

Yes I use phpmyadmin.  I think I know the issue now that you have been describing it.  As I am testing this validation script I am making I have been inputting dummy data into the above table.  There are many fields with '0' for mobile which are duplicate entries which already exist.  Maybe when this INSERT statement executes with another mobile 0 it is seeing this as not unique and throwing the error?

with another mobile 0...the error message you've quoted to us says you're inserting '' (i.e. an empty string), not 0. So that specific error isn't about the use of 0. And your PHP code 'mobile' => '' is inputting an empty string. P.S. Not sure how you managed to get multiple 0s in there on different rows when there is a unique constraint on the column - unless perhaps they were added before the constraint was created, and the database engine is tolerant of that (without testing I'm not sure how it deals with that scenario).

uq_mobile is a unique constraint (that's what the "uq" inside its name as well as the error message is suggesting) and once you attempted to insert a record, you passed a non-null value to it which ended being duplicated.
'mobile' => '',

from your code will insert an empty string as mobile which will succeed once, but the second time it will fail. The error message clearly specifies that you attempted to insert an empty string, so this must have been the reason.
The constraint protects your data integrity, because it's clear that a mobile number may belong to a single person, so when you are trying to insert a second user with the same mobile number as used for another one, then the RDBMS will infer that something's wrong and notify you about the problem.
